# Why don't these string expressions print the same result?

Tags: ruby

Why does this expression:

```
puts "abc" * 5
```

=> "abcabcabcabcabc"

not equal this expression?

```
5.times do puts "abc"
```

abc

abc

abc

abc

abc

=> 5

Could you please explain why they don't print the same result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first writes the string "abc" concatenated to itself five times:

```
"abc"*5 = "abc"+"abc"+"abc"+"abc"+"abc" = "abcabcabcabcabc"
```

The second piece of code writes "abc" using the puts function 5 times. The puts function writes a newline character after each message, meaning that it writes "abc\n" 5 times.

```
5.times do puts "abc"
```

turns to

```
puts "abc"         ->also jumps to the next line
puts "abc"         ->also jumps to the next line
puts "abc"         ->also jumps to the next line
puts "abc"         ->also jumps to the next line
puts "abc"         ->also jumps to the next line
```

Comment: in other words, the first one goes to the store and buys 5 chocolate bars. the second one goes to the store 5 times and buys one chocolate bar each time.

Comment: Actually, the first one goes to the store and buys the same chocolate bar 5 times, the second one goes to the store 5 times buys one different chocolate bar every time.

Answer (score 1):

you can replace puts with print, which doesn't add the new line at the end

```
5.times do print "abc"
end
```

abcabcabcabcabc => 5